# How do I increase the font size of the Unity Game Engine's editor UI in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: gnome, fonts, games, display-resolution

Is there a way to make the Unity Game Engine's editor UI font size larger? The font size on the editor view is different than the size of the menu bar's and the rest of the applications I run on my computer (presumably 1.25x as I am using Gnome Tweaks to set my font scaling to 1.25).

If I had to guess, the Unity editor only seems to be using the default 100% scaling setting for its embedded content. I am using Ubuntu 20.04 on GNOME with a 1080p monitor resolution (1920x1080).

[image: Screenshot - Small Font on Unity Game Editor UI]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with that program but, in general if a program doesn't have a font setting I use:

```
xandr --dpi 128
```

or

```
xandr --dpi 144
```

from the command line and then load the program.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, I found an answer on as I was playing around with settings!
The Unity Editor uses GTK (Or did, at least as of 2018), which seems to have compatibility trouble with Gnome Tweaks's display scaling setting.

[image: Screenshot - 1.25x Scaled Editor Font on Unity Game Editor UI]

What fixed it for me was in Settings > Displays to enable "Fractional Scaling" and set the scaling to my desired resolution. (And afterwards, in Gnome Tweaks resetting the Scaling Factor to 1.00).

However, this setting does have the warning label "May increase power usage, lower speed, or reduce display sharpness"; so be wary and test things out for your own usage.